# How to use the BIM 360 Web Viewer (Autodesk Forge)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How to use the BIM 360 Viewer mentioned on this article (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-viewer-vs-forge-viewer)?

I tried to find on the autodesk forge documentation, but didn't get anything.

I'm already use the "normal" viewer on my application.

Comment: What exact functionality from the BIM 360 Viewer do you need?

Comment: Hi, Adam. Thanks for the answer. So, I need to show multiple models (IFC files) at the same time in the viewer. I did it in the normal viewer, however the models do not overlap properly (differences in Z rotation). I believe it is a characteristic of files imported into the viewer. I wanted to test the BIM viewer to see if there is any control in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

The **BIM 360 Viewer** is not for 3rd parties and is only used inside **BIM 360**, but it's built on the public **Forge Viewer** and apart from a couple of **BIM 360** specific functionality the difference in behaviour would come from the **profile** settings used and the **extensions** loaded - as also mentioned in the article you pointed out.

You said that the issue seems to be with positioning/orienting when loading multiple models. By default, the **Viewer** automatically sets **placementTransform** and **globalOffset** to bring the models to the center, but you can override that when loading a model, see
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7

Hopefully, using that should help solve the problem.

Comment: Thank for the help, Adam. I already imagined that the BIM viewer was an internal solution from autodesk services. Therefore, I will try the approach suggested by the article you posted. Thanks again.